Building Android 13 (ARM64) for the Linux Aarch64 Android emulator
I'm trying to build Android 13 (ARM64) for the Android emulator (linux/aarch64). I managed to correctly start Android 12 (ARM64) images with the following setup, but I fail to do the same for Android 13.

I build the source code with lunch target lunch sdk_phone_arm64-userdebug and the following build command on a x86_64 server: "source ./build/envsetup.sh && lunch sdk_phone_arm64-userdebug && m && m emu_img_zip"

I then copy/unzip the emulator image artefacts to my linux arm64 machine using the zip file in the build out directory under: "out/dist/sdk_phone_arm64-img-eng.ubuntu.zip"

I use the lastest emulator binary for linux aarch64 from: https://ci.android.com/builds/branches/aosp-emu-master-dev/grid?legacy=1

I then try to start the emulator with the following command:
/android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Arm64 -no-window -no-snapshot -ports "5556,5557" -grpc "8556" -skip-adb-auth -no-snapshot-save -logcat "*:V" -show-kernel -logcat-output "/tmp/android-unknown/logcat.log" -shell-serial "file:/tmp/android-unknown/kernel.log" -no-boot-anim -wipe-data -gpu swiftshader_indirect -qemu -append "panic=1" -cpu max -machine gic-version=max &


For Android 12 this setup and commands work well and the emulator starts correctly. However, for Android 13 the emulator gets stuck when trying to load the images. The kernel is stuck in an endless reboot and shows the following error:
kernel: [    1.346161][    T1] uart-pl011 9000000.pl011: no DMA platform data
kernel: [    1.349940][    T1] VFS: Cannot open root device "(null)" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6
kernel: [    1.350060][    T1] Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
kernel: [    1.350306][    T1] 0100            8192 ram0 
kernel: [    1.350383][    T1]  (driver?)
kernel: [    1.351598][    T1] 0101            8192 ram1 
kernel: [    1.351617][    T1]  (driver?)
kernel: [    1.351711][    T1] 0102            8192 ram2 
kernel: [    1.351723][    T1]  (driver?)
kernel: [    1.351808][    T1] 0103            8192 ram3 
kernel: [    1.351820][    T1]  (driver?)
kernel: [    1.351906][    T1] 0104            8192 ram4 
kernel: [    1.351917][    T1]  (driver?)
kernel: [    1.352000][    T1] 0105            8192 ram5 
kernel: [    1.352011][    T1]  (driver?)
kernel: [    1.352094][    T1] 0106            8192 ram6 
kernel: [    1.352106][    T1]  (driver?)
kernel: [    1.352185][    T1] 0107            8192 ram7 
kernel: [    1.352196][    T1]  (driver?)
kernel: [    1.352274][    T1] 0108            8192 ram8 
kernel: [    1.352285][    T1]  (driver?)
kernel: [    1.352365][    T1] 0109            8192 ram9 
kernel: [    1.352376][    T1]  (driver?)
kernel: [    1.352469][    T1] 010a            8192 ram10 
kernel: [    1.352480][    T1]  (driver?)
kernel: [    1.352571][    T1] 010b            8192 ram11 
kernel: [    1.352582][    T1]  (driver?)
kernel: [    1.352744][    T1] 010c            8192 ram12 
kernel: [    1.352760][    T1]  (driver?)
kernel: [    1.352847][    T1] 010d            8192 ram13 
kernel: [    1.352860][    T1]  (driver?)
kernel: [    1.352962][    T1] 010e            8192 ram14 
kernel: [    1.352974][    T1]  (driver?)
kernel: [    1.353063][    T1] 010f            8192 ram15 
kernel: [    1.353075][    T1]  (driver?)
kernel: [    1.353296][    T1] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
kernel: [    1.353515][    T1] CPU: 2 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.15.41-android13-8-00030-gc66cde32ee51-ab8840540 #1
kernel: [    1.353688][    T1] Hardware name: linux,ranchu (DT)
kernel: [    1.353866][    T1] Call trace:
kernel: [    1.353921][    T1]  dump_backtrace.cfi_jt+0x0/0x8
kernel: [    1.354014][    T1]  dump_stack_lvl+0x80/0xb8
kernel: [    1.354083][    T1]  panic+0x180/0x444
kernel: [    1.354140][    T1]  mount_block_root+0x1ac/0x270
kernel: [    1.354206][    T1]  mount_root+0x68/0x90
kernel: [    1.354257][    T1]  prepare_namespace+0x164/0x1e8
kernel: [    1.354321][    T1]  kernel_init_freeable+0x120/0x19c
kernel: [    1.354390][    T1]  kernel_init+0x40/0x36c
kernel: [    1.354528][    T1]  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x20
kernel: [    1.354844][    T1] SMP: stopping secondary CPUs
kernel: [    1.355408][    T1] Kernel Offset: disabled
kernel: [    1.355480][    T1] CPU features: 0x2,200011e3,20000846
kernel: [    1.355630][    T1] Memory Limit: none
kernel: [    1.368911][    T1] Rebooting in 1 seconds..


It seem that for some reason the root fs can't be correctly mounted. However, with Android 12 images this works fine. So how do I need to adjust the build and starting process for Android 13 images?
Update:
If I used the additional sdk module the kernel detects the partitions but avb fails: "source ./build/envsetup.sh && lunch sdk_phone_arm64-userdebug && m && m emu_img_zip"
kernel: [    2.326708] EXT4-fs (vdd1): recovery complete
kernel: [    2.328027] EXT4-fs (vdd1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: errors=remount-ro,nomblk_io_submit. Quota mode: none.
kernel: [    2.331535] init: [libfs_mgr]check_fs(): mount(/dev/block/pci/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/by-name/metadata,/metadata,ext4)=0: Success
kernel: [    2.340460] init: [libfs_mgr]umount_retry(): unmount(/metadata) succeeded
kernel: [    2.342534] init: [libfs_mgr]Not running /system/bin/e2fsck on /dev/block/vdd1 (executable not in system image)
kernel: [    2.346563] EXT4-fs (vdd1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: . Quota mode: none.
kernel: [    2.349029] init: [libfs_mgr]__mount(source=/dev/block/pci/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/by-name/metadata,target=/metadata,type=ext4)=0: Success
kernel: [    2.352748] init: Failed to copy /avb into /metadata/gsi/dsu/avb/: No such file or directory
kernel: [    2.356374] init: [libfs_mgr]Created logical partition system on device /dev/block/dm-0
kernel: [    2.359123] init: [libfs_mgr]Created logical partition system_dlkm on device /dev/block/dm-1
kernel: [    2.362074] init: [libfs_mgr]Created logical partition system_ext on device /dev/block/dm-2
kernel: [    2.364862] init: [libfs_mgr]Created logical partition product on device /dev/block/dm-3
kernel: [    2.367299] init: [libfs_mgr]Created logical partition vendor on device /dev/block/dm-4
kernel: [    2.369287] init: DSU not detected, proceeding with normal boot
kernel: [    3.376310] init: [libfs_avb]Device path not found: /dev/block/by-name/system
kernel: [    3.378664] init: [libfs_avb]Fallback to use logical device path: /dev/block/dm-0
kernel: [    4.384217] init: [libfs_avb]Device path not found: /dev/block/by-name/system
kernel: [    4.385757] init: [libfs_avb]Fallback to use logical device path: /dev/block/dm-0
kernel: [    4.388395] init: [libfs_avb]total vbmeta size mismatch: 6720 (expected: 6208)
kernel: [    4.396205] init: [libfs_avb]Failed to verify vbmeta digest
kernel: [    4.397695] init: [libfs_avb]vbmeta digest error isn't allowed 
kernel: [    4.399311] init: Failed to open AvbHandle: No such file or directory
kernel: [    4.400961] init: Failed to setup verity for '/system': No such file or directory
kernel: [    4.402834] init: Failed to mount /system: No such file or directory
kernel: [    4.404555] init: Failed to mount required partitions early ...
kernel: [    4.415023] init: InitFatalReboot: signal 6
kernel: [    4.425984] init: #00 pc 000000000031f8c8  /init (UnwindStackCurrent::UnwindFromContext(unsigned long, void*)+88)
kernel: [    4.427662] init: #01 pc 0000000000311b7e  /init (android::init::InitFatalReboot(int)+94)
kernel: [    4.429092] init: #02 pc 0000000000312033  /init (android::init::InstallRebootSignalHandlers()::$_24::__invoke(int)+19)
kernel: [    4.431357] init: #03 pc 00000000004d99d0  /init (__restore_rt)
kernel: [    4.432597] init: #04 pc 00000000004ce77e  /init (abort+190)
kernel: [    4.433782] init: #05 pc 0000000000317ceb  /init (android::init::InitAborter(char const*)+27)
kernel: [    4.435544] init: #06 pc 000000000048aecc  /init (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+60)
kernel: [    4.438285] init: #07 pc 000000000048a69e  /init (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+350)
kernel: [    4.440081] init: #08 pc 0000000000307012  /init (android::init::FirstStageMain(int, char**)+10354)
kernel: [    4.441980] init: #09 pc 00000000004c5cce  /init (__real_libc_init(void*, void (*)(), int (*)(int, char**, char**), structors_array_t const*, bionic_tcb*)+718)

